# Unable to install nextflow correctly

Tags: nextflow

I've attempted to install Nextflow with command "curl get.nextflow.io | bash" in my Windows system command prompt-bash, but I consistently see this error: Unable to initialize nextflow environment

In parallel, on a remote server, the Nextflow is installed with the same command and I can verify that with ls command. However, when I prepare a sample script (hello.nf), executing it by "nextflow run hello.nf" shows that Nextflow is not characterised.

In any of cases, typing "nextflow info" doesn't recognise nextflow. Is there anyway that I can install Nextflow or have I missed any step? I have also tried with wget, but no success yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 10 Version 1903 with Build 18362 or higher, you can use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#whats-new-in-wsl-2) rather than having to configure a Linux VM. There's a few hoops to jump through, but this guide (Oct 2021) should be sufficient: [Setting up a Nextflow environment on Windows 10](https://www.nextflow.io/blog/2021/setup-nextflow-on-windows.html)

On your remote machine, all you should need to do is to move your `nextflow` to somewhere in your `$PATH`. Alternatively, you can just call it with `./nextflow` (assuming it is in your current directory).